# Blit pixels from one image to bitmap without scaling

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am creating an image from file by using

```
var img = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

I also create a Bitmap with the same size

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
```

then I draw from the image to the bitmap using

```
var r = new Rectangle(tileoffsetx, tileoffsety, tilewidth, tileheight);

g.DrawImage(img, destx, desty, r, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

I have also tried

```
var r = new Rectangle(tileoffsetx, tileoffsety, tilewidth, tileheight);

g.SetClip(r);

g.DrawImageUnscaled(img, destx, desty);
```

In both cases, I have get unexpected scaling.
(Even when I am using the DrawImageUnscaled version).

In both cases, I get a result that is around 1/3 the size of the original.

That seems to correspond with the fact that the image has a resolution of 300 pixels/inch and the bitmap a resolution of 96 pixels/inch.

How do I copy pixels regardless of pixels / inch?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, you may find a lack of interest in providing a good answer (though you likely will get a number of "shots in the dark", and who knows, maybe one of those will help). It's unclear from your question what the original source image is (another bitmap?) and if it's a bitmap, why you don't just use that instead of copying it (since you seem to want the new bitmap the same size as the original). Have you considered simply setting the resolution of the new bitmap to the same as the original? Your question lacks many important details.

Comment: You need to set both graphic objects to the same dpi resolution. Pick which!

Comment: Drawing with GDI+ is a huge mess, don't be surprised by anything. Have you tried the `DrawImage` overload that takes 2 rects? Specify the source and destination rectangles, *including* width and height, explicitly. Also, just ignore the `DrawImageUnscaled` methods, you will not find them useful.

Comment: @AndersLindén Don't think too much of it. The current state of stackoverflow is: Don't know the answer -> downvote & close-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried an idea from the comments, using the form of drawImage that takes 2 rects. It goes like

```
var srcrect = new Rectangle(tileoffsetx, tileoffsety, tilewidth, tileheight);
var destrect = new Rectangle(destx, desty, tilewidth, tileheight);

g.DrawImage(img, destrect, srcrect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

and that succeeded!